После переноса проект ан другой ПК пишет ошибку
ошибка такая:


Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':app'.

* Try:
> Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
> For more on name expansion, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:name_abbreviation in the Gradle documentation.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 777ms
Build operation 'Build finished for file system watching' started
Completing Build operation 'Build finished for file system watching'
Build operation 'Build finished for file system watching' completed
Releasing file lock for cache directory md-supplier (C:\Users\���\.gradle\caches\8.2\md-supplier)
Releasing lock on cache directory md-supplier (C:\Users\���\.gradle\caches\8.2\md-supplier).
Releasing file lock for Build Output Cleanup Cache (C:\androidSDK\AndroidStudioProjects\new\MyApplication4\.gradle\buildOutputCleanup)
Releasing lock on Build Output Cleanup Cache (C:\androidSDK\AndroidStudioProjects\new\MyApplication4\.gradle\buildOutputCleanup).
Releasing file lock for cache directory md-rule (C:\Users\���\.gradle\caches\8.2\md-rule)
Releasing lock on cache directory md-rule (C:\Users\���\.gradle\caches\8.2\md-rule).
Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 4, disk reads: 1 (avg: 0.003 secs, total: 0.003 secs)
Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.001 secs
Completing Build operation 'Run build'
Build operation 'Run build' completed
Daemon worker: released lock on worker lease
Stopping 0 deployment handles
Stopped deployment handles
Releasing file lock for checksums cache (C:\androidSDK\AndroidStudioProjects\new\MyApplication4\.gradle\8.2\checksums)
Releasing lock on checksums cache (C:\androidSDK\AndroidStudioProjects\new\MyApplication4\.gradle\8.2\checksums).
Releasing file lock for file hash cache (C:\androidSDK\AndroidStudioProjects\new\MyApplication4\.gradle\8.2\fileHashes)
Releasing lock on file hash cache (C:\androidSDK\AndroidStudioProjects\new\MyApplication4\.gradle\8.2\fileHashes).
VCS Checkout Cache (C:\androidSDK\AndroidStudioProjects\new\MyApplication4\.gradle\vcs-1) has last been fully cleaned up 4 hours ago
Cache VCS Checkout Cache (C:\androidSDK\AndroidStudioProjects\new\MyApplication4\.gradle\vcs-1) was closed 0 times.
Cache VCS metadata (C:\androidSDK\AndroidStudioProjects\new\MyApplication4\.gradle\8.2\vcsMetadata) was closed 0 times.
Releasing file lock for dependencies-accessors (C:\androidSDK\AndroidStudioProjects\new\MyApplication4\.gradle\8.2\dependencies-accessors)
Releasing lock on dependencies-accessors (C:\androidSDK\AndroidStudioProjects\new\MyApplication4\.gradle\8.2\dependencies-accessors).
dependencies-accessors (C:\androidSDK\AndroidStudioProjects\new\MyApplication4\.gradle\8.2\dependencies-accessors) has last been fully cleaned up 4 hours ago
The daemon has finished executing the build.



файлы .lock удалял из папки 8.2.
подскажите, в чем причина ошибки ?

ask 'wrapper' not found in project ':app'. не достаточное объяснение?

file lock for cache directory md-supplier - эта строка наводит на мысль, что ПК блокирует доступ этой директории, попробуйте запустить от имени администратора

я добавлял код task wrapper(type: Wrapper){
gradleVersion = '7.2'
} Но не помогло. Новая ошибка вылетает
